# page freeze when parsing a large JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to load a 8MB json file using JSON.parse in Javascript, but the page would freeze for about 1-2 minutes, is there a way to parse async and put a loading info or even percentage info improving the user interface?

I google'd a little bit found jsonstream (https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream), my understanding is that it's for nodejs? and could not understand that.

If someone have some simple example shown would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: So, you need multiple threads to avoid freezing your UI? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage

Comment: Thank you @sebnukem, this seems useful to me and I'll try to do some research! Thanks again!

Comment: Storing it in a DB and only pulling the parts you need is probably a better bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing which might work is to use webworkers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage

This moves the parsing process into a separate thread, which functionally would parse your file asynchronously.

Let's say you have main.js and worker.js.  In main.js you could have something like:

```
var myWorker = new Worker("worker.js");
myWorker.postMessage(jsonValue); //jsonValue = your json file

myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
  var parsedJSON = e.data;
  console.log('Message received from worker', parsedJSON);
}
```

And then in your worker.js file you could have:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(e.data)
  postMessage(parsedJSON);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying this approach. For my case if it's better to use some database approach, like mongoDB? I heard a lot about mongodb, but actually don't have a concept.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. If you're creating a web application which manipulates data on some 8mb JSON file, it would be better to have that stored in a database, like mongoDB where you can access what you need rather than reparsing that every single time on the client side.